# How do I limit spaces in regex python?

Tags: python, regex

Hi I would like to limit spaces in the following examples:

```
Text_1 = 'Your email: Peter @gmail.com Please enter your spouse's email: Mandy@gmail.com'
Extracted_1 = 'Peter @gmail.com'
Target_1 = 'Peter @gmail.com' (correct)

regex_pattern = r'Your email: [\s]?(.+@[\w.,-]+)'

Text_2 = 'Your email: Please enter your spouse's email: Mandy@gmail.com'
Extracted_2 = 'Please enter your spouse's email: Mandy@gmail.com'
Target_2 = '' (Empty)
```

With my current pattern, it will end up extracting everything up till the 2nd email.
Is there a way where I can limit number of spaces?

Eg. limit 2 spaces so the 2nd example will return empty

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude matching the @ to not cross it when matching.

Note that `\s` can also match a newline, and `[\w.,-]+` is a character class also allowing for example only `,,,`

```
\bYour email:[^\S\n]+([^@\n]+@[\w.,-]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5bh6TA/1)